# Get FieldInfo of inherited class

Tags: c#, reflection

In C# I have classes which are derived in the following way:

```
MyClass1 <- MyClass2 <- MyClass3 <- MyClass4 (The root class is MyClass1)
```

Now I have an instance of MyClass4 myClass4. How to get a private field info declared in MyClass2? I can do the following:

```
FieldInfo[] fields = model.GetType().BaseType.BaseType.
                       GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (FieldInfo fld in field)
{
    ....
}
```

What if the inheritance level is unknown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know you are looking for a field in `MyClass2`? If so, keep reading `CurrentType.BaseType` until `CurrentType == typeof(MyClass2)`.

Iow

```
Type lCurrentType = model.GetType();
while (lCurrentType != typeof(MyClass2) && lCurrentType != null)
{
    lCurrentType = lCurrentType.BaseType;
}
```